# Call Spring actuator /restart endpoint from Spring boot using a java function

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator

I'm looking to restart the spring boot app, so using  Spring  Actuator  /restart endpoint is working using curl, but i'm looking to call the same function using java code from inside the app, i've tried this code, but it's not working:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        RestartEndpoint p = new RestartEndpoint();
        p.invoke();
    }
});
thread.setDaemon(false);
thread.start();
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to inject the RestartEndpoint:

```
@Autowired
private RestartEndpoint restartEndpoint;

...

Thread restartThread = new Thread(() -> restartEndpoint.restart());
restartThread.setDaemon(false);
restartThread.start();
```

It works, even though it will throw an exception to inform you that this may lead to memory leaks:

> The web application [xyx] appears to have started a thread named
> [Thread-6] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a
> memory leak. Stack trace of thread:

- Note to future reader of this question/answer, **RestartEndpoint** is NOT included in `spring-boot-actuator`, you need to add `spring-cloud-context` dependency.

Comment: 1+, as far as I see from the source code, you also need `"management.endpoint.restart.enabled=true", "management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=restart`

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the json here

```
@Autowired
private HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint;

public Health getAlive() {
    return healthEndpoint.health();
}
```

2. Add custom logic