# Spring Cloud Config refresh configurations

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

Is it possible to refresh the configurations calling a java method instead to use the REST api:

`curl localhost:8080/actuator/refresh -d {} -H "Content-Type: application/json"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ResartEndpoint class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39386168/programatically-restart-spring-boot-application-refresh-spring-context) from `spring-cloud-context`:

```
@Autowired
private RestartEndpoint restartEndpoint;

...

Thread restartThread = new Thread(() -> restartEndpoint.restart());
restartThread.setDaemon(false);
restartThread.start();
```

This is how @[alexbt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/641627/alexbt) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38851994/9705485) to do it. But note that the spring cloud documentation also says you can [refresh individual beans](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Dalston.SR5/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html#_refresh_scope) provided they are RefreshScope.

Comment: Thanks. Just a question, there is a reason why you use the restartEndpoint in a thread?

Comment: It makes sense to invoke it asynchronously (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47634569/9705485) but I'm not sure you need to do this anymore as it seems to have been added to the underlying code in v2 - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/commit/f7519a30ad0a02b63a113ff66621bf6c6991d251#diff-344ead166eff93b62c827e6f8ff1caed